# What is MongoDB read and write locking process?

Tags: mongodb

What is the process by which MongoDB GridFS handle reads and write? 
Support there a 3 clients accessing MongoDB all at the same time, 2 clients reading the same file stored and a 3rd client is writing.

- Will Client 1 and 2 get the file that is still incomplete supposing that Client has not finished updating an existing file?
- If Client 3 is still writing would Client 1 and 2 be able to read the previously saved / stored file?
- What is the policy of MongoDB GridFS on writing and reading locking?

[image]

**Update:**

The clients here could be from 1 to n, where all can be reading and writing at the same time.

Comment: [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/) is just "driver level software". So there **is no server side sync** since it's **not** a "server process".

Comment: I mean locking, sorry.

Comment: Does not matter. It's **not a server process**. Just so we are clear here. [From the official Spec Document](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/gridfs/gridfs-spec.rst#abstract) *"GridFS is a **convention drivers use** to store and retrieve BSON binary data (type “\x05”) that exceeds MongoDB’s BSON-document size limit of 16MB.*". So you are asking how MongoDB handles this. The answer is **it does not "handle" it at all. Nothing to "handle" here**